# Connect to host oracle database from inside the container

Tags: java, oracle, docker, containers, keycloak

Hi so Im facing this problem which I'm not able to connect to oracle database from inside the container, Im using keycloak image but don't think that does matter because when I run it locally it works fine but it can't detect the port on the localhost from inside the container this is the error

```
2024-03-05 12:00:37,814 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
2024-03-05 12:00:39,966 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=o4V7gJfoQkyngTkFPGwGew==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12541/
2024-03-05 12:00:39,968 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.lambda$delegateWork$1(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:273)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.buildSessionFactoryOptionsBuilder(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:81)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:74)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
        at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:156)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:64)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2024-03-05 12:00:40,318 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2024-03-05 12:00:40,367 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2024-03-05 12:00:40,473 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2024-03-05 12:00:41,103 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2024-03-05 12:00:41,153 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_444305, Site name: null
2024-03-05 12:00:41,172 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=0uoi2gStTgG7XUByvXYseQ==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12541/
2024-03-05 12:00:41,238 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-03-05 12:00:41,239 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2024-03-05 12:00:41,239 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=0uoi2gStTgG7XUByvXYseQ==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12541/
2024-03-05 12:00:41,239 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=0uoi2gStTgG7XUByvXYseQ==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12541/
2024-03-05 12:00:41,240 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6

ENV KC_DB=oracle
ENV KC_DB_URL_HOST=localhost
ENV KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=xe
ENV KC_DB_URL_PORT=1521
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=keycloak
ENV KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false

#Enable HTTP
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true

# Enable health support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true

# Enable metrics support
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true


ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

I even changed my  listener.ora to this

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_xe\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle_xe\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle_xe\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

and tsnames.ora to this

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle_xe\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

any guess why it doesn't work I tried many things, strangely it works fine with postgres but I'm guessing the problem is in oracle or in docker

here is how I run the image

```
podman run --network=host my-custom-image start-dev
```

Thanks in advance